# Time Series clustering

Tags: time-series, cluster

I have financial time series and PCA scores, that I'm trying to cluster. As PCA scores don't have orientation, I would like to know what clustering method would be suitable for clustering these kind of series? I feel that -1 correlation series with my PCA scores is as important as +1 correlation and should be clustered together.

Comment: I would use k-means.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, is there preferred similarity matrix method? I have used correlations, but there is alot to choose from (wavelet, DTW)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a purely statistical question and as such would better fit at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Sure, thought that it would fit under Quantitative Finance, but cross validated might be better then. Thanks for effort.